# Python module YahooFinancials TypeError: string indices must be integers

Tags: python

yahoo_financials.get_key_statistics_data(), Suddenly started throwing error: TypeError: string indices must be integers. Not sure anybody using this python module experiencing the error.

```
from yahoofinancials import YahooFinancials

ticker = 'AAPL'
yahoo_financials = YahooFinancials(ticker)

conentKeys = yahoo_financials.get_key_statistics_data()

    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/raj/opt/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/runpy.py", line 194, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "/Users/raj/opt/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/Users/raj/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2022.20.1/pythonFiles/lib/python/debugpy/adapter/../../debugpy/launcher/../../debugpy/__main__.py", line 39, in <module>
    cli.main()
  File "/Users/raj/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2022.20.1/pythonFiles/lib/python/debugpy/adapter/../../debugpy/launcher/../../debugpy/../debugpy/server/cli.py", line 430, in main
    run()
  File "/Users/raj/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2022.20.1/pythonFiles/lib/python/debugpy/adapter/../../debugpy/launcher/../../debugpy/../debugpy/server/cli.py", line 284, in run_file
    runpy.run_path(target, run_name="__main__")
  File "/Users/raj/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2022.20.1/pythonFiles/lib/python/debugpy/_vendored/pydevd/_pydevd_bundle/pydevd_runpy.py", line 321, in run_path
    return _run_module_code(code, init_globals, run_name,
  File "/Users/raj/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2022.20.1/pythonFiles/lib/python/debugpy/_vendored/pydevd/_pydevd_bundle/pydevd_runpy.py", line 135, in _run_module_code
    _run_code(code, mod_globals, init_globals,
  File "/Users/raj/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2022.20.1/pythonFiles/lib/python/debugpy/_vendored/pydevd/_pydevd_bundle/pydevd_runpy.py", line 124, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/Users/raj/Code/Machine_Learning/wb-starter/scrap_yahoo_finance3.py", line 7, in <module>
    conentKeys = yahoo_financials.get_key_statistics_data()
  File "/Users/raj/opt/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/yahoofinancials/__init__.py", line 613, in get_key_statistics_data
    return self.get_clean_data(self.get_stock_tech_data('defaultKeyStatistics'), 'defaultKeyStatistics')
  File "/Users/raj/opt/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/yahoofinancials/__init__.py", line 492, in get_stock_tech_data
    return self.get_stock_data(statement_type='keystats', tech_type=tech_type)
  File "/Users/raj/opt/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/yahoofinancials/__init__.py", line 476, in get_stock_data
    dict_ent = self._create_dict_ent(self.ticker, statement_type, tech_type, report_name, hist_obj)
  File "/Users/raj/opt/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/yahoofinancials/__init__.py", line 409, in _create_dict_ent
    re_data = self._scrape_data(YAHOO_URL, tech_type, statement_type)
  File "/Users/raj/opt/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/yahoofinancials/__init__.py", line 169, in _scrape_data
    stores = data["context"]["dispatcher"]["stores"]["QuoteSummaryStore"][tech_type]
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

Comment: You're making us guess where the error is.  Please edit the question and add the whole error traceback message.

Comment: Its a bug in the `yahoofinancials` package, raise an issue on its github repo to get a resolution.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not tech support; if using someone else's library **by itself in a [mre], as advertised in the documentation** produces an error, then that is either a bug (which should be reported on the project's issue tracker) or a configuration issue (which is addressed by using a support forum for the software, reading the documentation carefully, or again perhaps the issue tracker).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Updating yahoofinancials to the latest module 1.7 fixed it for me: https://pypi.org/project/yahoofinancials/

Comment: Updating the library does not help at all.